# Windows full redirect keyboard input

Tags: windows, redirect, keyboard

There are PC with 2 USB keyboard KeyboardA and KeyboardB

User1 work on KeyboardA.

Some time User2 type on KeyboardB.

Task: all input from KeyboardB redirect to file.

If I use SetWindowsHookEx I can hook input and stop message, but can`t detect KeyboardA or KeyboardB (there way to detect what the keyboard?)

If I use RegisterRawInputDevices I detect KeyboardA or KeyboardB, but can`t stop message and input from KeyboardB translate to User1 interface (there are way to stop message?).

May be I need anoter way for ridirect data from keyboard to specific place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solutions:

1. With SetWindowsHookEx block all input
2. In RawInput determine keyboard
3. If it`s KeyboardA resend input in active window
4. If it`s KeyboardB redirect input
5. For disable block in item 1 I check KeyboardHookStruct.Flags on LLKHF_INJECTED and not 
   block

[Detalis](http://ase.com.ua/?p=130)